# Modificar tipo de dato sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de modificar un tipo de dato de varchar(20) a varchar(50) tengo este query `ALTER TABLE ALUMNO MODIFY DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(40);` pero tengo un error cerca de `MODIFY`:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.
```

Alguien me podria ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu sentencia se corresponde mas a MySQL y Oracle.

Si estas en Sql Server debes usar lo siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE ALUMNO
ALTER COLUMN DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(40);
```

[***Aquí tienes ejemplos con otros motores***](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)